# Can a transitive relation be represented by a utility function?

Tags: game-theory, utility, algorithmic-game-theory

I am currently studying for my Game Theory exam and came across a question that seems pretty basic but somehow can't wrap my head around. So if you could share some insight with me, that would be greatly appreciated.

The question is,
"Every transitive relation on three alternatives can be represented by a utility function."

The answer is "False".

However, I thought transitivity means "For all x, y, z in A, if (x >= y) and (y >= z) then (x >= z)" So then, wouldn't a utility function also preserve this relation? That is, wouldn't it also be "if u(x) >= u(y) and u(y) >= u(z), then u(x) >= u(z)?" How come every complete relation on two alternatives can be represented by a utility function (this was another question on the quiz), but a transitive relation cannot be?

I'm confused... Any help would be appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good question. I suppose they might be considering an example like the following:

$$ x \succeq z, \hspace{1cm} y \succeq z, \hspace{1cm} x \text{ and } y \text{ are incomparable.}$$

Obviously this example is transitive (or doesn't violate transitivity, at least). But it is not complete as $x$ and $y$ are incomparable. If you slap any utility function on this, then either $u(x)>u(y)$, in which case $x \succ y$, $u(y)>u(x)$, in which case $y \succ x$, or $u(x)=u(y)$, in which case $x \sim y$. But each of these cases imply $x$ and $y$ are comparable, when we know they shouldn't be.

As for why a complete relation on two alternatives can definitely be represented,  the fact that it is complete means that either $x \succeq y$, $y \succeq x$ or both. If just the first is true, let $u(x)>u(y)$. If just the second is true, let $u(y)>u(x)$. If the third is true, let $u(x)=u(y)$. In each case, we can represent the relation with a utility function.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. However, I'm struggling to understand your transitive example. I guess I'm mostly confused about why it doesn't violate transitivity. Isn't it already violated when you can't compare x and y and thus cannot draw a conclusion that x⪰z? Or am I just misunderstanding the definition of transitivity?

Comment: No problem. All transitivity says is that IF $x \succeq y$ and $y \succeq z$, THEN it must also be the case that $x \succeq z$. A violation of transitivity then has to have the IF part hold, and the THEN part fail to hold. Here the IF part doesn't hold, so transitivity is not violated, i.e. the preferences are transitive. Does that help at all?

Comment: That doesn't make sense to me. If the IF part doesn't hold this means that this is not a transitive relation. How come a non-transitive relation can be a proof of a statement where the pre-condition is to be a transitive relation?